# Clifton chronicles book 4 phrase meaning

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I found the phrase when Sebastian says it to his mother ‘I have daily lessons at the foot of an expert. And what’s more, I’m his only pupil,’. Please explain it to me.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: The one in the quotes...

Comment: What don't you understand?  The quote has more than one word.

Comment: The entire quote..

Comment: What specific words???  Are you saying you don't understand "I'm his only pupil"??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"At the foot of" is only a slight change from the traditional idiomatic phrase which is "**at the feet of**" and which means "in the position of a disciple or a subject or a suppliant of" (SOED); given the context the meaning must be the same.

"I'm his only pupil" states an  obvious  consequence by mentioning the cause: since he/she is the only pupil he/she is sure to get much more attention from the teacher.

Comment: Thank you for the answer...